# How to update the countries of publication in the new console of Google Play android?

Tags: android, google-play-console

According to the google play console documentation, you must go to the price / distribution tag, but this option is not found in the new version of google play console.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7550024?hl=en